# Meaning of this power system line diagram symbol

Tags: power, transformer, three-phase, energy, symbol

Please explain to me what this symbol means, in single line diagram?

> [image: project diagram showing the unknown symbol]

Source of image: My project diagram.

Here is another example I found:

> [image: webpage diagram including the unknown symbol]

Here is a magnified part, showing the symbol:

> [image: magnified symbol]

Source of the above 2 images: [Electrical Engineering Portal - Understanding Substation Single Line Diagrams and IEC 61850 Process Bus (Depicting Relay Circuits)](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/substation-single-line-diagrams-iec-61850)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context - zooming out a bit to some of the surrounding schematic to give a better overview of what it might be indicating in the circuit

Comment: And say what country the drawing was made it. This may tell us which standard was used.

Comment: Sorry , really I would like to know in this kind if schematics, with relays. In this kind this IS known as block if tests, with signals and functions. I think It is used yo clase the circuito of the block if test, but I think It has a particular name

Comment: @TomCarpenter. Tom could you se better now?? I would like to share yo you my original schematics with this kind if symbol but the image is yo heavy

Answer (score 5):

According to ANSI Y32.2/IEEE 315 standards, it's short circuit termination.

[image]

Source is aforementioned standards document.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have posted another question, about the placement if a shortcircuit symbol or termination symbol in an valve , followed by the earth symbol. I don't understand this layout. The point is, if It is already the earth symbol, why It is necessary to put the termination or shortcircuit symbol? I post the image of the valve in this loop.