# Symbol of short circuit (or termination) with an Earth

Tags: power, resistance, three-phase, solar-energy, standard

Can someone explain to me why the symbol of the valve arrester has a short circuit, if it is already earth? I don't understand why it is depicted like this.

Why does the valve arrester have the symbol of a short circuit joined with earth? Does it mean that it is a short circuit to earth?

[image: wiring diagram]

Note: The CD symbol is a streamer, equipment which measures current.

Context: I posted a previous question: [Meaning of this power system line diagram symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706225/meaning-of-this-power-system-line-diagram-symbol). *That* question was to ask what the termination symbol was. Now I understand that. *This* question is asking why in a valve symbol, with a streamer, there IS a termination symbol or a short circuit symbol as in the link cited above, and why is this symbol followed by the earth symbol and not only the valve, streamer and the earth?

Summary: I would like to know why they put a termination symbol *and* an earth symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it shows a connection to its own case (chassis) which is then connected to earth by a  wire (or other type of conductor) that is separate to it's own case.  Kind of a "feed-through" connection.

Do you have a photo of the item in question?

Edit: added the following below:

> I would like to know why they put a termination symbol and an earth symbol.

Reason: to ensure the reader understands that a **separate conductor** is required to complete the connection to earth.  This is important in situations such as sub-stations, where the details of earthing conductors become very important for both functional and safety reasons, as compared to PCB design where a net-name (such as GND or OV) can be used to indicate a connection to a ground plane, so that a separate earthing conductor is not required.

Comment: No sorry I only have the single line diagram in which It has ome arrester valves.

Comment: This symbol means the termination

Comment: Do you have the physical item, or just the schematic?

Comment: I only have the schematic

Comment: Your question contained "why in a valve symbol, with a streamer".  What physical items are you referring to by the words "valve" and "streamer"?