# Why does the valve symbol have a Clase symbol,or short-circyit symbol before the earth

Tags: power, heat, three-phase, generator, energy

Could anyone explain to me why the valve symbol have a shortcircuit symbol or termination symbol before the earth???[image]

Comment: Daniel Prieto López - Hi, Just to be clear: As far as I can tell, this question is not a duplicate of your [earlier question](/q/706225). There you were asking about the meaning of a specific symbol. But here you are asking about the overall meaning of a *combination* of that symbol (which apparently means a short-circuit) followed by the earth symbol. Is that correct? || Please note that when someone asks multiple similar & related questions, as you have done, it can sometimes happen that people misinterpret them as duplicates - because they are similar.

Comment: (continued) Therefore please [edit] this question and add extra context. For example, link to your earlier question. Explain that you now understand what that symbol means *on its own*. And then explain clearly that you are asking about the *combination* of those multiple symbols (if that is what you are asking about). OK? If you clarify & explain the differences between your question, then they are less likely to be confused as duplicates. || Finally, I know there are some language differences here, but "Clase" (in the title) does not seem to be an English word. Please fix/clarify.

Comment: @SamGibson you may be correct but, I think I got the link wrong to the duplication. This is what I meant to link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706285/symbol-of-short-circuit-or-termination-with-an-earth <-- in that question he asks this: *Can someone explain to me why the symbol of the valve arrester has a short circuit if it is already earth?* <-- which is virtually identical language to that used in this question.

Comment: @Andyaka - Thanks, that makes more sense as the dup. The OP has now updated that question you just linked (in a way similar to what I suggested here, but I'm not sure if the OP has read my comments here or not), to clarify why "[Symbol of short circuit (or termination) with an Earth](/q/706285)" isn't a dup of "[Meaning of this power system line diagram symbol](/q/706225)". || I will change the duplicate shown in the "duplicate closure banner" above the question here, to be the correct one that you mention.

Comment: Daniel Prieto López - Hi, As you can see in the comments just above, it's now clear that *this* question is a duplicate and should stay closed. However I see that you have edited question "[Symbol of short circuit (or termination) with an Earth](/q/706285)" to explain why that one isn't a duplicate  of "[Meaning of this power system line diagram symbol](/q/706225)". I will now go and review that situation.

Comment: Hello @SamGibson. I would appreciate so much if you could provide help me for this question. Thanks in advance

Comment: @DanielPrietoLópez - I saw your edit to the earlier question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/706285 - I have tried to improve and clarify that, to help make the context clearer about why that isn't a duplicate. Please check my edit there. You can change it again, if needed. || I have also reopened it, now that you have added that explanation. (I don't know the actual answer, however - I have never worked with industrial electrical wiring diagrams like that one.) || To be clear, *this* question is a duplicate and will not be reopened - do you understand that?

Comment: @DanielPrietoLópez - Please also note my comment on [this previous question of yours](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/706225), as the required reference(s) for the source(s) of the copied images, are missing.

Comment: @SamGibson. Yes I agree with you, but this images are from files which aren't on internet. They are from a businesse project. Well I could. Share a one drive file with the clarification

Comment: @DanielPrietoLópez - I'm not suggesting that you add links to private project schematics. You can just add the text that they are private project schematics. The concern is these images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyA20.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyVZh.jpg). They seem to have been copied from a website screenshot. It is those ones, which are not your own work, which are the main concern. Do you see that? Can you add the required source reference(s) for them? I don't know if they come from the same webpage or not. Is the 2nd one just a magnification from the 1st one?

Comment: @SamGibsom. Yes One is a magnification from the other. I have justo put the link on where It was got

Comment: @DanielPrietoLópez - Thanks for adding that reference. I have improved the details there. || I think my work here is now finished :)